# shape or scene management for pyglet?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I very much like pyglet, but the basic unit of abstraction is a vector of coordinates, which is unweidly, and not the level of abstraction I'd want when designing a complex scene.

Are there any libraries that are "commonly" used with pyglet to manage shapes and compose them into scenes? Does everyone write their own `Shape` base-class from scratch?

I can imagine a system that gives an easy-to-use interface to objects and scenes, but under the hood interacts with Pyglet using batches and vectors in a fairly optimal way. In essence: does this exist already, or is it something that still needs written?

Answer (score 3):

[Cocos2D](http://cocos2d.org/) is a sprite-oriented framework built on top of pyglet (and has now grown a [smartphone-oriented version](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) too). It provides a [Scene](http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/scenes.html) abstraction that works like a basic state machine, and allows for relevant content to be organised into one or more [Layers](http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/layers.html). Both Scenes & Layers are nodes in the scene graph, allowing for transitions & effects to be applied at any point and affecting everything hierarchically beneath that point.

While its focus is on 2D, you should be able to easily leverage its Scenes into dealing with 3D instead.

There's also [PyGly](http://adamlwgriffiths.github.com/PyGLy/), which I'm not familiar with, but which does seem to offer some [scene graph](http://adamlwgriffiths.github.com/PyGLy/docs/api_scene_graph.html) support.

Answer (score 0):

I googled "pyglet scenegraph" - just to find only one suspect [OOgler](https://github.com/mshaw/OOgler), which seems kinda abandoned(last commit - 3 years ago). Seems like noone was too interested to invest in creation of a really sophisticated framework using **pyglet**. Though your at least could check [OOgler](https://github.com/mshaw/OOgler)  as example of such an attempt.